# Activated carbon filter vs. Reverse osmosis filter

Tags: toxicity, filtering

I have a 5 month old baby and I'm currently using an activated carbon water filter with the city tapwater supply (I live in Mumbai, India and the water can be highly polluted sometimes with all sorts of things - bacteria and viruses, pesticides and other organic compounds, lead, mercury, arsenic, etc.).

My baby is due to start solids and water soon.  Should I install a reverse osmosis filter instead, because that supposedly eliminates all particles that are larger than a water molecule (yes, the beneficial minerals like calcium, iron, etc. would be gone but I would rather want all the harmful chemicals removed).

Comment: Check this website: http://www.kinetico.com/blog/post/ro-vs-carbon-filtration.aspx